# In the following proof of Newton's method, how to show the Fréchet derivative is invertible in a neighborhood of the root?

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods

When reading [Kendall and Weimin's book "Theoretical numerical analysis"](https://books.google.dk/books?id=Tg6p72yydEMC&pg=PA238&dq=kendall%20theoretical%20numerical%20analysis%20theorem%205.4.1&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpnJ_f7N_SAhWGCywKHcpGAQ8Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=kendall%20theoretical%20numerical%20analysis%20theorem%205.4.1&f=false), I got stuck with the invertibility of the Fréchet derivative.

Suppose $U$, $V$ are two Banach spaces and $F: U \rightarrow V$ is Fréchet differentiable. We want to solve the equation $F(u) = 0$ and Newton's iteration reads $u_{n+1}=u_n - [F'(u_n)]^{-1}F(u_n)$. The following theorem is excerpted from the book:

**Theorem 5.4.1.** *(Local Convergence) Assume $u^\star$ is a root of the equation such that $[F'(u^\star)]^{-1}$ exists and is a continuous linear map from $V$ to $U$. Assume further that $F'(u)$ is locally Lipschitz continuous at $u^\star$, that is*,
$$
||F'(u)-F'(v)|| \leq L ||u-v||,\mbox{  for any $u, v \in N(u^\star)$}
$$
*where $N(u^\star)$ is a neighborhood of $u^\star$, and $L>0$ is a constant. Then there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $||u_0 - u^\star|| < \delta$, the Newton's sequence $\{u_n\}$ is well-defined and converges to $u^\star$. Furthermore, for some constant $M$ we have the error bounds*
$$
||u_{n+1}-u^\star|| \leq M ||u_n-u^\star||^2
$$
*and*
$$
||u_n-u^\star|| \leq (M\delta)^{2^n}/M
$$

**Proof.** Upon redefining the neighborhood $N(u^\star)$ if necessary, we may assume $[F'(u)]^{-1}$ exists on $N(u^\star)$ and $c_0 = \sup_{u \in N(u^\star)}||[F'(u)]^{-1}|| < \infty$...

**My Question:** My question concerns exactly *how*, by redefining $N(u^\star)$ if necessary, can we assure that $F'(u)$ is invertible and $c_0 < \infty$. I'm guessing whether it holds that *if the bounded linear map $K: V \rightarrow W$ is invertible then for any bound linear map $A: V \rightarrow W$ close enough to $K$, $A$ is invertible* (I know this holds if $V$ and $W$ are identified). If I were able to prove this proposition then I would have shown a required $N(u^\star)$ can be constructed. But I doubt the truthfulness of the proposition I just raised...

At any rate, any hint is welcomed and will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) and the related result that if $A:U\to V$ is boundedly invertible, then for all $B:U\to V$ in the neighborhood of $A$ defined by
$$
\|B-A\|\le\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}
$$
also $B$ is boundedly invertible, with $T=I-A^{-1}B$
$$
B^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty T^kA^{-1}
$$
and 
$$
\|B^{-1}\|\le \frac{\|A^{-1}}{1-\|T\|}\le\frac1{\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}-\|B-A\|}
$$

---

In your case $A=F'(x^*)$ and $B=F'(x)$ with $\|B-A\|\le L\|x-x^*\|$. Then use
$$
\|x-x^*\|<δ=\frac12(L\|F'(x^*)^{-1}\|)^{-1}
$$
or with a smaller $δ$ so that $B(x^*,δ)$ is still contained in the domain of differentiability of $F$.

Comment: Hinted by your answer I got how to prove the proposition and arrived at the desired conclusion. Many thanks!